# How do I call a method from an instance of a class?

Tags: objective-c

```
-(NSDictionary *)properties;
+(NSDictionary *)ClassProperties;
```

Now, how can I call ClassProperties from sub-classes?

```
-(NSDictionary *)properties {
    return [? ClassProperties];
}
```

The point is that `ClassProperties` gets the list of properties in the class, so i can't call the base class definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Along the lines of Marc's response, you could more generally call the method with

```
[[self class] ClassProperties]
```

In fact, if your base class and all the subclasses implement `+ (NSDictionary *)ClassProperties`, then your base class can do this

```
- (NSDictionary *)properties {
    return [[self class] ClassProperties];
}
```

and then none of your subclasses will need to know about `- (NSDictionary *)properties`.  The correct class method would be called based on what `self` is.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the class name of the subclass.