# Calling a class method from an instance method

Tags: objective-c

I want to call a class method from an instance method to use its return value.

This is my class method

```
+(double) minFMFrequency {

    return 88.3;
}
```

and this is my instance method

```
-(void) chackFrequency {

    switch (band) {
        case 'F':
            if (self.frequency > Value obtained from class method )
                frequency=107.9;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

`band` and `frequency` are instance variables.

Comment: So you want to know what to put in place of `Value obtained from class method`? What have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-c: call class method within same class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290156/objective-c-call-class-method-within-same-class)

Comment: i tried self.minFMFrequency , 
[self minFMFrequency]

Answer (score 13):

```
+(void)classMethod
{
    [self anotherClassMethod]; // in a class method, self refers to the class
}

-(void)instanceMethod
{
    [self anotherInstanceMethod]; //in an instance method self refers to the object, or instance 

    [[self class] classMethod]; //to call a class method from an instance send the instance the class message

}
```

so in your case: `[[self class] minFMFrequency];`

Comment: when i try to do so i get this error: Thread1 : signal SIGABRT

Comment: but not because of this code. you should post a new question with your code and all error informations.

Answer (score 0):

Dupe. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429841/how-do-i-call-a-method-from-an-instance-of-a-class).

You need to do: `[[self class] ClassProperties]`

So... for you:
within `chackFrequency` you can call `[[self class] minFMFrequency]`.

Comment: when i try to do so i get this error: Thread1 : signal SIGABRT